# User control used as a class

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a class and a user control. The user control is supposed to represent the class and contain all its properties. I'm kind of lost on how to handle this problem

all help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems that you should define an interface instead of a class and the user control implement this interface.

Comment: Do you mean you have a ViewModel class with the data you want to represent and a View class that will format the data in the ViewModel to be shown?

Comment: @YetAnotherSoftwareDeveloper I doubt he is using MVC since user controls don't exist there (IIRC). I would bet he is using WebForms.

Comment: i want to use the usercontrol so i can make instances of the class simply by placing a user control in the form. im working in simple windows forms in visual studio 2012

Comment: @UweKeim I didn't know anybody did WebForms anymore :) Glad he got an accepted answer though.

Comment: @YetAnotherSoftwareDeveloper _I_ am doing lots of WebForms. After yet another MVC 4 project I am more convinced that WebForms is the way to go. I really do think MVC (at least Microsoft's idea of) is horrible.

Comment: @UweKeim I used to do web forms then switched to Microsoft's MVC. At first I hated it. My first question was where is my WYSIWYG? Now that I understand the MVC Framework I love it. To me WebForms is an elaborate hack by Microsoft to get WinForms developers to go to the web. I made that move. Moving to support MVC now web development is web development not WinForms that runs in a browser. Sure I had to learn html, css, javascript, jQuery and EntityFramework but it was worth it!

Comment: @YetAnotherSoftwareDeveloper For me, the ugly thing is mixing markup and code like it's 1999 and classic ASP. Bäh!

Comment: @UweKeim the aspx syntax is ugle the razor syntax is much cleaner looking. This page has a side by side chart of Razor vs ASPX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to use data binding.
Create a property typed with your class e.g. `MyClass Data {get; set;}`, then add new BindingSource and as BindingSource.DataSource set your Data property. Then design your control.
Do not forget to create new instance of MyClass in constructor.